# I am trying to get elasticsearch and flask to work. Here is the error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'elasticsearch'

Tags: python, flask

Here is the tutorial I am using.
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search

First example below.

Some of the code below contains`from app import create_app`. It is slightly different in the second example.

```
wsgi.py

from flask_migrate import Migrate
   
from app import create_app, db

from app.config import Config

app = create_app(Config)

 
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
app.config.from_object(Config)


**app/models.py **
 
class class Posts(UserMixin, db.Model):
    searchable__ = ['document']
 
class Config(object): 
#...
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL = 'http://localhost:9200'
 
 
 
 
 
 
**app/__init__.py**
# ...
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
# ...
 
def create_app(Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
 
    # ...
    app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']]) \
        if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None
 
    # ...
 
**routes.py**
 
 
from app import create_app
 
def add_to_index(index, model):
    if not create_app.elasticsearch:
        return None
    payload = {}
    for field in model.__searchable__:
        flash(model.__searchable__)
        flash(field)
        payload[field] = getattr(model, field)
    create_app.elasticsearch.index(index=index, id=model.id, document=payload)
 
 
@userinfo.route("/")
@userinfo.route("/home")
def home():
    # .query.all() means I get all info from the database.   
    # use a try if the Posts_db is empty then it will skip it
 
    try: 
        posts = Posts.query.all()
    except:
        posts = None
 
    add_to_index('posts', posts)
 
 
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, title='home')
```

Here is the error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'elasticsearch' and the full error message is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcode\flaskblog2\app\userinfo\routes.py", line 75, in home
    add_to_index('post', posts)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcode\flaskblog2\app\userinfo\routes.py", line 50, in add_to_index
    if not create_app.elasticsearch:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'elasticsearch'
```

Second example below

I even changed

`from app import create_app`

to

`from flash import current_app`

and get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'searchable'
Here is the full error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\anaconda3.1\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcode\flaskblog2\app\userinfo\routes.py", line 75, in home
    add_to_index('post', posts)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcode\flaskblog2\app\userinfo\routes.py", line 53, in add_to_index
    for field in model.__searchable__:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__searchable__'
```

Can someone please help me fix the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exactly what the error message and stack trace are telling you it is.  The problem is in this line:

```
if not create_app.elasticsearch:
```

`create_app` is a function, per your definition:

```
def create_app(Config):
```

Function objects don't have an `elasticsearch` attribute, hence the error you are getting.

My guess is that you want to run this test on the `app` object created in your `create_app` function, since that object will have an `elasticsearch` attribute, and that attribute could be `None`.  I don't see that you save a reference to that object anywhere outside your `create_app` function.  Say you had the `create_app` function return `app`, and then you assigned that to a global via:

```
app = create_app(...)
```

Then it would make sense for the problematic line of code to be:

```
if not app.elasticsearch:
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it I will let you know if it works.

Comment: When I try importing ```from wsgi import app``` I get this error.  https://pastebin.com/McQhg6yR


When I try ```from app import app``` I get the same error. 

I assume when importing from wsgi,py I use ```from wsgi ... ``` and not ```from app...``` 


I will quickly also add wsgi.py to the code above. 

@CryptoFool

Comment: Just wanted to rephrase this ```from app import app``` gives the previous error ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__searchable__' ``` .